# read system call in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I want to read an integer and write if it is negative or positive . The problem is that the output is always positive even if I enter negative numbers. Furthermore the number is maximum 4 digits and I want it to be 4 bytes. Please note that I am a complete begginer in ARM assembly . Here is the code

```
.text
.global main


main:   
    mov r0, #0 /* read system call */
    ldr r1, =inp_str
    mov r2, #4
    mov r7, #3
    swi 0

    cmp r1,#0   
    blt w2
    bge w1

w1:
    mov r0, #1 /* write system call */
    ldr r1, =string1
    mov r2, #len1
    mov r7, #4
    swi 0
    b e

w2:
    mov r0, #1 /* write system call */
    ldr r1, =string2
    mov r2, #len2
    mov r7, #4
    swi 0

e:
    mov r0, #0 /* exit system call */
    mov r7, #1
    swi 0

.data
    string1: .ascii "positive "
len1 = . - string1
    string2: .ascii "negative "
len2 = . - string2
    inp_str: .asciz "%d"
```

Comment: Did You check with debugger what is realy read? I suspect You are comparing to number of read items, but not to a value read (`cmp` instruction).

Comment: You haven't given any important details of your environment - what is the "read" call supposed to return, and in which registers? What are you expecting to be in r1 instead of a string pointer after the call? Is it limited to 4 characters because of the #4 in r2?

Comment: As far as I know read returns how many bytes have been read. r0 has the number of standard input , r1 is the register where the number is going to be stored , r2 is the number of bytes I am going to read and r7 is the number of system call. My "goal" is to store the number I type in the command line to register r1 . At first I run the program from command line ./test . Then I type a number like -4 and press enter. Then I am expecting to see something like negative in standard output.

Comment: The usual unix-style `read` system call reads text into a buffer. You need to convert that to number, or in this case just check if you got a minus sign. The `%d` specifier is a `scanf` thing, not `read`.

Answer (score 0):

When you type a number (like *1234*) you are not reading THE number *1234*, but the characters 1, 2, 3 and 4 (*49*, *50*, *51* and *52* in ASCII) (you read a String)
The read syscall stores theses values sequentially at the *inp_str* address on memory

When you type a negative number (like *-1234*) you are reading -, 1, 2, 3 and 4 (*45*, *49*, *50*, *51* and *52* in ASCII)

Another problem is that, after the syscall, you are comparing R1 with #0.
R1 does not hold the number you typed, but it holds the address represented by *inp_srt*. It's a memory address. It's always positive.

If you want to know if the number you typed is positive or negative, you would need to convert those characters (50, 51, 52 and 53) (remember: Always ASCII) to a real number... or you could use the function *scanf* to read (would be a lot easier)